# i++ does not work for var in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, var

I am trying to get multiple vars from a for loop. The url looks like this:

`total=2&id1=2&content1=I+am+the+first+blog&id2=4&content2=I+am+the+second+blog`

```
for (var i:Number=i; i<=total;i++){ 
 trace(i);
 var id = this.evt.target.data+i;
        var content = evt.target.data.content;
 trace ('id from DB: ' + id);
        trace ('content from DB: ' + content);
}
```

This line of code won't work. I have tried all kinds of ways:

```
var id = this.evt.target.data+i;
var id = ["this.evt.target.data"+i]; //traces var id as text only, not the result id1
var id = this.evt.target.data.i;
var id = this.evt.target.data[i];
var id = this.evt.target.data+i;
```

Is it impossible this way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is `evt`, `evt.target` and `evt.target.data` referring to? Are you trying to read FlashVars from the URL, or are you trying to read data, you opened via URLLoader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With very much guessing of what you are trying to do, I believe this is what you try:

```
// ...
private var loader:URLLoader;

public function foo ( someUrl:String ):void
{
    loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onComplete );
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.load( new URLRequest( someUrl ) );
}

private function onComplete ( event:Event )
{
    var total:int = int( event.target.data.total );

    for ( var i:int = 1; i <= total; i++ )
    {
        trace( event.target.data[ 'id' + i ] );
        trace( event.target.data[ 'content' + i ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your example, changed some values but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8888/lifestyle/get.php?type=blog");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.load(request);

function completeHandler(evt:Event) {

  //var blancData = evt.target.data.blancData;
  var total = evt.target.data.total;
  var id = evt.target.data.id;
  var content = evt.target.data.content;

  for (var i:Number=1; i<=total;i++){ 
    var id = evt.target.data.id;
    var content = evt.target.data.content;
    trace ('id uit DB: ' + id);
    trace ('content uit DB: ' + content);
    }

 // trace ('totaal rijen in DB: ' + total);
  //trace ('id uit DB: ' + id);
  //trace ('content uit DB: ' + content);
}
```

Comment: If I change var id = evt.target.data.id to var id = evt.target.data.id1; it does work, but when I change it to var I it doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

It works!!

@Poke thank you for your answer!! You've pointed me to the right direction!

```
var content = evt.target.data['content' + i];
```

Now I am going to slap myself because I didn't see this before :)